# Insert link to send an Intent in a string resource

Tags: java, android

I want to add a link in a string resourse item in an Android app.

I saw it is possible to insert a link like this

```
<string name="my_link"><a href="http://somesite.com/">Click me!</a></string>
```

But I don't want to launch a site, instead I want to send an Intent that will bring the user to his phone settings.

Is it possible to have a link like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DeepLinks](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) to handle specific `URL`s. To do it, you should introduce  an `Activity` as a handler of specific pattern `URL`. So when user clicks on the specific pattern link, your `Activity` can be selected as its handler and then you can open phone settings. Here is an implementation of this idea:

**manifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MyTransientActivity">

    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://somesite.com" -->
        <data android:host="somesite.com" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />

    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

**MyTransientActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MyTransientActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getIntent() != null) {
            String action = getIntent().getAction();
            if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                settingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(settingsIntent);
            }
        }
        finish();
    }

}
```

**Test:**

```
TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textview.setText(getString(R.string.my_link));
Linkify.addLinks(textview, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: @FrancescoRe: Did I understand your question right?

Comment: Hi, this is what I was looking for. I wish it could be done without a middle activity but that is not a problem...Thank you!

Comment: I tried to do it using `IntentService` first, but it seems that only Activity receives such intents.

Answer (score 0):

for what I know you cannot send it like that, you should add it like this:

```
<string name="my_link">http://somesite.com/</string>
```

And to send the intent you have to send it like this:

```
String url = this.getResources().getString(R.string.my_link);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
```

And this will open your android browser with the link you send it.
I hope this is useful. :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer however it seems it can be done with a middle activity.